# Iterate through letters of an unknown length of digits

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay... I need to iterate through strings with arbitrary lengths. Since I don't know how to explain this too well, I mean like this:

```
def zip(string1,string1):
    ...
```

and when called with `"a"` and `"ad"` it would return a list:

```
>>>zip("a","ad")
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","aa","ab","ac","ad"]
```

I've tried using `map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('nb')+1))` but I get `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found`, and I don't know where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: i was a bit confused at first, because zip is an actual python method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's it:

```
def zip_(start, end):
    def __inc(s):
        if not s:
            return "a"
        elif s[-1] != "z":
            return s[:-1] + chr(ord(s[-1]) + 1)
        else:
            return __inc(s[:-1]) + "a"

    s = start

    yield s
    while s != end:
        s = __inc(s)
        yield s


print list(zip_("a", "ad"))
```

A few comments:

1. Don't use the word `zip` as a name of a variable or a function, because it's already reserved.
2. In the solution `zip_` is a generator. I did it in order to not keep too much data in memory. If you need an exact list, just convert it as I've done in the print-statement.
3. In case of wrong arguments the function may go into an infinite loop. For example, if you call `zip_("b", "a")`. But actually it's easy to fix by adding a few lines if it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, and I like that it is a generator too!

Answer (score 1):

This is a base-26 number system and here is how I would solve it. And also `zip` is a python built-in function, probably better not to redefine it.

```
def alphaToNumber(s):
    r = 0
    for x in s:
        r *= 26
        r += ord(x) - 96
    return r

def numberToAlpha(n, result):
    head = (n - 1) // 26
    tail = chr((n - 1) % 26 + 97)
    if head == 0:
        return tail + result
    else:
        return numberToAlpha(head, tail + result)

def gen(start, end):
    start_n = alphaToNumber(start)
    end_n = alphaToNumber(end)
    return [numberToAlpha(x, "") for x in range(start_n, end_n + 1)]

print(gen("a", "ad"))

# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad']
```